# Numerical solution of 3 dim integral with singularity

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to solve the following integral numerically with Mathematica:

$\int_{0}^{L_x}\int_{0}^{L_y}\int_{0}^{L_z}d^3x'\frac{\sin^2(\frac{x'\pi}{L_x})\sin^2(\frac{y'\pi}{L_y})\sin^2(\frac{z'\pi}{L_z})}{|x-x'|}e^{i\omega |x-x'|}$

But I am not getting the result which I expect. Therefore I have the feeling that Mathematica cannot deal with the singularity of the integrand ($x\in [0,L_x]\times[0,L_y]\times[0,L_z]$). By the way: Does anyone know how to prove if the integral is finite?

I already tried different Methods/MinRecursion/MaxRecursion/MaxPoints in NIntegrate which more or less all yield the same result.

Here is my code:

```
Lx = 0.09;  
Ly = 0.03;  
Lz = 0.4;  
f = 10*10^9;  
c = 3*10^8;  
omega = 2*Pi*f/c;  
x = 0.045
y = 0.015
z = 0.15

B0 = Sin[Pi*xs/Lx]^2*Sin[Pi*ys/Ly]^2*Sin[Pi*zs/Lz]^2;  
Integrand = B0/((x-xs)^2+(y-ys)^2+(z-zs)^2)^(1/2)*Exp[I*omega*((x-xs)^2 +(y-ys)^2 +(z-zs)^2)^(1/2)];  


NIntegrate[Integrand, {xs, 0, Lx}, {ys, 0, Ly}, {zs, 0, Lz}];
```

The thing which worries me a little is that when I use Lx=0.09, Ly=0.03, Lz=0.4 and  evaluate the integral at  (x=(0.045,0.015,0.15)m) I get -0.00508-i 0.000606. But when I evaluate it at (x=(0.044,0.014,0.15)) I get -0.00024+0.000198. So there seems to be a discontinuity at (x=(0.045,0.015,0.15)m). All other points ($x\in [0,L_x]\times[0,L_y]\times[0,L_z]$) yield a much smaller results than the point at (x=(0.045,0.015,0.15)m). When I plot the results in the xy plane I have to exclude this point such that one can see the structure...

All comments are welcomed.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `xyz` is not defined.

Comment: In the formula, integration is carried out with respect to x', whereas in the code with respect to x. How really?

Comment: I edited my post and it should work now. You can play with the x and y values to see the feature which I mentioned in the post

Comment: In the Mathematica code the integration is also carried out with respect to x'. x' is indicated as xs in the code

Comment: I think the problem may be that at `x = x'`, `Sin[0]/0` converges while `Cos[0]/0` does not.  Try rationalizing all your numbers, increasing your `WorkingPrecision` and play with `Sin[omega ...]` instead of `Exp[I*omega ...]`.  When I do that I get closer numbers for the two data sets than you.

Comment: I have already done this. I computed the code with Exp replaced with Sin and anothertime replaced with Cos. In both cases I get the same result as if I just compute it with Exp. So I think also the integral with Cos converges...

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "When I do that I get closer numbers for the two data sets than you"?

Comment: There was a typo in the Latex formula. The x y z in the sin^2 also had to be primed. It is now corrected. Anyway in the mathematica code it was correct all the time

Comment: You should mention the error messages in your question.  They imply the difference in results are due to truncation error and are probably not a discontinuity.

Comment: Site tip: Use @username to make sure that a user is notified of your response.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a different rule/method and indicate the singularity:

First integral:

```
On@Assert;
Block[{x = 0.045, y = 0.015, z = 0.15},
 Assert[0 <= x <= Lx && 0 <= y <= Ly && 0 <= z <= Lz]; (* warn if outside domain *)
 NIntegrate[integrand, {xs, 0, x, Lx}, {ys, 0, y, Ly}, {zs, 0, z, Lz},
   Method -> "CartesianRule"]
 ]
Off@Assert;

(*  -0.00024633 + 0.000202509 I  *)
```

2nd integral:

```
On@Assert;
Block[{x = 0.044, y = 0.014, z = 0.15},
 Assert[0 <= x <= Lx && 0 <= y <= Ly && 0 <= z <= Lz];
 NIntegrate[integrand, {xs, 0, x, Lx}, {ys, 0, y, Ly}, {zs, 0, z, Lz},
   Method -> "CartesianRule"]
 ]
Off@Assert;

(*  -0.000246293 + 0.000198098 I  *)
```

They seem reasonably close.

Note the original answer used the following, which emits a slow convergence warning but gives the same result to ten nonzero digits and is much faster:

```
Block[{x = 0.044, y = 0.014, z = 0.15},
 NIntegrate[integrand, {xs, 0, Lx}, {ys, 0, Ly}, {zs, 0, Lz}, 
  Method -> "CartesianRule"]
 ]
```

The `NIntegrate::slwcon` slow convergence warning does not in itself indicate an error.  If the integral had failed to converge, it can help diagnose the problem.  However, for the other parameter setting `x = 0.045, y = 0.015, z = 0.15`, the integral had a small but significant error and had only five digits of precision, which is not horrible.